# Is this a valid abstract factory design pattern?

Tags: design-patterns

I'm using a variant of the abstract factory pattern as defined in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory

The pattern is coded on wikipedia like so -

```
/* GUIFactory example -- */

interface GUIFactory {
    public Button createButton();
}

class WinFactory implements GUIFactory {
    public WinButton createButton() {
        return new WinButton();
    }
}
class OSXFactory implements GUIFactory {
    public OSXButton createButton() {
        return new OSXButton();
    }
}


interface Button {
    public void paint();
}

class WinButton implements Button {
    public void paint() {
        System.out.println("I'm a WinButton");
    }
}
class OSXButton implements Button {
    public void paint() {
        System.out.println("I'm an OSXButton");
    }
}


class Application {
    public Application(GUIFactory factory) {
        Button button = factory.createButton();
        button.paint();
    }
}

public class ApplicationRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Application(createOsSpecificFactory());
    }

    public static GUIFactory createOsSpecificFactory() {
        int sys = readFromConfigFile("OS_TYPE");
        if (sys == 0) {
            return new WinFactory();
        } else {
            return new OSXFactory();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using it slightly differently in that I dont't need a further layer of abstraction to override paint behaviour in Button implementations.

My Code is -

```
    //Implmentation code
                  MainMenuButtonFactory mainMenuButtonFactory = new SyncButtonFactory();
                   BitmapButtonField refreshButton = mainMenuButtonFactory.createButton();    

        public interface MainMenuButtonFactory {

            BitmapButtonField createButton();

        }

        public class SyncButtonFactory implements MainMenuButtonFactory{

            public BitmapButtonField createButton() {

                return new BitmapButtonField(ButtonImageFactory.getResyncBitmap(),
                       ButtonImageFactory.getResyncBitmapHighlight()){
                   public boolean navigationClick(int status, int time)
                    {
                       FutureContent.future.clearContent();
                       ScreenController.displayNextScreen(new UpdatingScreenAnimation(Constants.MAIN_MENU_SCREEN));

                       return super.navigationClick(status, time);
                    }
                };

            }

        }

public class JudgeButtonFactory implements MainMenuButtonFactory{

    public BitmapButtonField createButton() {

        BitmapButtonField judgeButton = new BitmapButtonField(ButtonImageFactory.getJudgeBitmap(), 
                ButtonImageFactory.getJudgeBitmapHighlight()){
       public boolean navigationClick(int status, int time)
          {
        RatingsScreenController ratingsScreenController = new RatingsScreenController("MainMenuScreen");
        Thread t = new Thread(ratingsScreenController);
        t.start();

           return super.navigationClick(status, time);
          }
      };

      return judgeButton;
    }

}
```

Is this still a valid abstract factory design pattern ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as long as you have an interface to create a kind of objects and provide one implementation, you are implementing an abstract factory.

But consider:

- Are you going to need multiple implementations of the factory? If you are not, then you do not need this pattern
- Are you going to use the factory in multiple places? If you are not, you don't need a factory (just a build method somewhere).

Comment: Yes, I have multiple implementations of the MainMenuButtonFactory but these implementations are just called from one class.

Comment: The salient feature of an abstract factory is that methods produce compatible objects. In your example: Windows style buttons go with Windows-style combo boxes. And with this pattern you CAN'T get it wrong

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you just haven't shown all the code to concentrate on the `paint` question you pose, but I'd expect to see other `XXXButtonFactory implements MainMenuButtonFactory` classes too. And these would create variations of `BitmapButtonField`'s parent class/interface.

If you don't have any others, or all your `MainMenuButtonFactory` derived classes just create `BitmapButtonField` classes, with no variation then the Abstract Factory does not seem like the appropriate pattern. Compare this to the Facory variations that then create `WinButton`/`OSXButton` in the example.

In this sense, the lack of a `paint` method in itself is not an issue ... but I would have expected to see evidence of some variation in the created classes. If not `paint`, then what variation are you modelling that justifies the use of the Abstract Factory?

Comment: The variation that occurs is the line - ScreenController.displayNextScreen(new UpdatingScreenAnimation(Constants.MAIN_MENU_SCREEN));